# Additional ColorScheme in Swift/SwiftUI beside Dark Mode and Light Mode

Tags: swift, swiftui, color-scheme, ios-darkmode

I'm working on an App that **usually** will be used in dark environments and the light output from the display should be reduced to a minimum. So I want to have a low-contrast with really black backgrounds and grey text.
If someone is using that App in another environment the user might consider a usual view with higher contrast - so for example the usual dark or light mode.
Of course I can set all `background`s to black and `foregroundColor`s to gray, but that would require a lot of code to give the user the possibility back to change to usual light / dark mode.
MY approach was rather to write an `extension` to `ColorScheme`, starting with

```
public extension ColorScheme {
static let evenDarker = ColorScheme.dark
}
```

and adjusting the colorvalues from there.
In my imaginiation this should have created a copy of `.dark`. I can call

```
  let contentView = ContentView()
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .evenDarker)
```

and it builds without problems, unfortunately it does show the system-setting (as defined on the device) and not a copy of the dark mode. Calling the same view with `.dark` or `.light` overrides the system setting though.

Besides I can't find any list or documentation of possible values in the ColorScheme - e.g. how to override the default background color from gray to black.
Did anyone ever get this or something similar get to work?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found a solution that works for the first question:
Working with

```
public extension UIUserInterfaceStyle {
static let evenDarker = UIUserInterfaceStyle.dark }
```

and

```
window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .evenDarker
```

works better, it copies `.dark` to `.evenDarker` - and different from using the environment-setting of the ContentView() it also has an option to use `.unspecified` - if the user wants to use the system setting.